# chrome Arguments to disable save password prompt

Tags: google-chrome, passwords, arguments, prompt, disable

I need to disable Chrome's saved password prompt through command line, just like the following format:
--headless
--disable-gpu

these not working:
--disable-save-password-bubble
--disable-notifications
--credentials_enable_service=false
--profile.password_manager_enabled=false

Please help, thanks a lot!!
Since i need to load extension, so, i can not use --incognito, though it can do disable prompt.

[check image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dKlTW.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below config ->

```
    ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
    Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    prefs.put("credentials_enable_service", false);
    prefs.put("profile.password_manager_enabled", false);

    chromeOptions.setExperimentalOption("excludeSwitches", singletonList("enable-automation"));
    chromeOptions.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't exactly disable the save password prompt, but if you open chrome in guest mode (--guest) the option doesn't appear.